# BottomNavigationBar not able to apply background image - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, background-image, flutter-bottomnavigation

**BottomNavigationBar** is not applying background image  when there is more than 3 **BottomNavigationBarItem**. It shows white background instead of applied image. Please review the code and let me know if I'm missing something in the code.

```
 bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/images/tabbar_background.png'), fit: BoxFit.fill),
            ),
            child: BottomNavigationBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0,
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset("assets/images/eplay.png"), title: Text('title')),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset("assets/images/games.png"), title: Text('title')),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset("assets/images/retail-location.png"), title: Text('title')),
                 BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset("assets/images/scan.png"), title: Text('title')),
                /*  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset("assets/images/scan.png"), title: Text('title')),
*/
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed` as a property of the `BottomNavigationBar`.

---

I added a demo using your code as an example:

```dart
  bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/images/tabbar_background.png'), fit: BoxFit.fill),
            ),
            child: BottomNavigationBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed, // new line
              elevation: 0,
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset("assets/images/eplay.png"), title: Text('title')),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset("assets/images/games.png"), title: Text('title')),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset("assets/images/retail-location.png"), title: Text('title')),
                 BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset("assets/images/scan.png"), title: Text('title')),
                /*  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset("assets/images/scan.png"), title: Text('title')),
*/
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: Background image is working now. But i want type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting as per my requirement. Any help?

Comment: Background image doesn't appear. I see white background.

Comment: So according to the docs `If [type] is null then [BottomNavigationBarType.fixed] is used when there
  are two or three [items], [BottomNavigationBarType.shifting] otherwise.`

Comment: So I cannot use BottomNavigationBarType.shifting with background image?

Comment: If you are using the `shifting` type, you have to give the `selectedItemColor` and `unselectedItemColor` , that could be a reason a white screen appears.

Comment: If my answer helped you with the problem specified in your original post, please accept it. If not, provide more detail as to why it does not.